# How to prevent spread operator to change the original array?

Tags: php

I am having two arrays in php 7.4.16

```
$data_one = array(
    ['id' => 491, 'default' => false],
    ['id' => 492, 'default' => false],
    ['id' => 493, 'default' => true],
);
```

and

```
$data_two = array(
    ['id' => 491, 'default' => false],
    ['id' => 492, 'default' => true],
    ['id' => 493, 'default' => false],
    ['id' => 494, 'default' => false],
);
```

I am using the spread operator:

```
$data_one = [...$data_two];
```

is adding the missing array with id 494 to $data_one .... but also is overwriting the value for "default" in the $data_one. (in the first array with id 492 the default will become true, and id 493 will become false)

How can I add the new entries from $data_two to $data_one but keep the original values ("default") from $data_one ?

** UPDATE **

the final array should look like this

```
$data_one = array(
    ['id' => 491, 'default' => false],
    ['id' => 492, 'default' => false],
    ['id' => 493, 'default' => true],
    ['id' => 494, 'default' => false],
);
```

Comment: You're not merging arrays, you're replacing the entire value of `$data_one` with `$data_two`.

Comment: Use `array_merge()` if you want to merge arrays.

Comment: Sorry, `array_merge()` isn't correct for this. I thought it was an associative array.

Comment: There's no built-in function that will work for this, you need to write a loop. Or you could convert the arrays to associative, merge them, then convert back to 2-dimensional.

Comment: Also, `array_merge()` won't do replacement when the keys are numbers. It ignores the keys and just concatenates the values into a new array whose keys start at `0`.

Comment: I think you should index these by id. That will make this merge much easier, and you can easily switch back to standard numeric indexes afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through the elements in `$data_two`. Check if its `id` already exists in `$data_one`. If not, add it.

```
$ids = array_column($data_one, 'id');
foreach ($data_two as $item) {
    if (!in_array($item['id'], $ids)) {
        $data_one[] = $item;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the spread operator (`array_merge()` on array values only, surrogate for `array_values()`) with the [*array union* operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) over the *id-indexed* `$data_one` and `$data_two` arrays with `$data_two` being on the right-hand side:

```php
$id = 'id';
$idx = static fn(array $data) => array_column($data, null, $id);

$result = [
    ... $idx($data_one)
      + $idx($data_two)
];
```

Only the values of new entities (identity by their *id*) are appended.

All `id`s should be integers.

If you're not interested in the resulting array keys, you can also keep them:

```php
$id = 'id';
$idx = static fn(array $data) => array_column($data, null, $id);

$result = $idx($data_one)
        + $idx($data_two)
        ;
```

And a more generic PHP code example on 3v4l.org: https://3v4l.org/2Lk8R (PHP 5.5+ variant).